# Ionic 3 app - URL not changing as you browse through app in browser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have been using Ionic 1 for years and I am *slowly* trying to teach myself Ionic 3/4. I have very little experience with TypeScript, so I like to look at other peoples code and projects to try and follow the logic. I have been using this project lately for some self-paced learning and I have a question as to why the URL doesn’t change when the project is **served through the browser**.

This is the project I have been trying to learn from: https://github.com/candelibas/instaclone

Typically, as you move from tab to tab, or from view to view, you would see the URL change as you move through the app. In this project, the URL stays the same versus updating anything after the hashbang (#).

Is this something that is configurable, or did the author just take a different approach when designing the code?

Thanks for any info or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This app does not seem to use a router which would be responsible for updating the URL. They just push a new component onto the [`ion-nav`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav) stack.

IMHO this is perfectly fine for smaller projects or themes that don't need to update the URL.

If you want to add routing, Ionic recommends using the [Angular Router](https://angular.io/guide/router) in combination with Ionic's [`ion-router-outlet`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router-outlet).